# Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: linux, apache, bind, virtualhost, vps

I'm trying to set up my VPS to host two domains. The virtual host section of the httpd.conf is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost www.siteA.com>
    DocumentRoot /home/XXXXX/public_html/siteA
    ServerName www.siteA.com
    <Directory "/home/XXXXX/public_html/siteA">
         allow from all
         Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.siteb.com>
DocumentRoot /home/XXXXX/public_html/siteb/
<Directory "/home/XXXXX/public_html/siteb/">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I enter the domains into a browser, both resolve to the same site ( to the site that is first in the httpd.conf file). Is there anything obviously wrong with the above?

Aside from this, when I registered the two domain names, I also registered two sets of nameservers (ns1/ns2.siteA.com & ns1/ns2.siteB.com) and the IP address of both of these are the same, as I currently only have a single IP address. Could this also be a problem? I don't think it is, but its probably worth mentioning.

Other info: Apache 2.2.3 running on Centos 4. Using a mixture of command line editing (mostly) and Webmin 1.5 to control the VPS.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 NameVirtualHost www.siteA.com
 NameVirtualHost www.siteB.com
```

to the recipe. From the [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost):

> The NameVirtualHost directive is a required directive if you want to configure
>    name-based virtual hosts.

Comment: Super that seems to have done the trick - though siteB.com (without the www) is still resolving to siteA.com; thats probably something trival though?

Comment: @user try dropping the www in the NameVirtualHost. However, you are explicitly mentioning the www, you may need to add `ServerAlias` entries for the non-www part (and possibly separate NameVirtualHosts, don't know)